# wget in path does not work in freebsd

Tags: path, freebsd

I have just installed a freeBSD 7 in my VMWare.however I found no wget in this os.so I download wget-1.15.tar.gz from websit. and then install wget on my os.

then I meet this strange question below.

```
# wget
wget: Command not found.
# whereis wget
wget: /usr/local/bin/wget
# env | grep PATH
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
# ln -s /usr/local/bin/wget /bin
# whereis wget
wget: /bin/wget
# wget
wget: Command not found.
# /bin/wget
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
#
```

why when I type /bin/wget,system can find wget;when I type wget ,system can't find wget.you see that /bin already in my PATH.
thanks.

Comment: The laat attempt at least executed it, but you gave it no work to do.  Perhaps your shell caches path contents?

Comment: Sorry,I mean that why when I type /bin/wget,system can find wget;when I type wget ,system can't find wget.you see that /bin already in my PATH.you know why.thanks again

Comment: Some shells cache the result of a path scan and so don't see added programs.

Comment: After reboot,it works.thanks.

Comment: That sounds a lot like the shell caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default shell on FreeBSD is `tcsh`. After you've added a program, you need to use the `rehash` command for `tcsh` to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, use 'fetch' command.

Example:

```
# fetch https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/Python-3.4.4.tar.xz
```